# c++ getline() line has weird numbers additionaly instead of just chars as entries

Tags: c++, vector, getline

I've tried to read a file and put every single char in a 2d vector matrix (`vector<vector<char>>`), but when I use `getline()` the line does not only contain the chararcter, but also some number and when I try to access the values of the line with e.g. `line[1]`, I get something like 49 '1'. But all I want is the '1' and I don't know what 49 is and how to get rid of it.

`matrix` is a predefined type `vector<vector<char>>`

```
matrix mapMatrix;
ifstream map(pathToMap);
if (!map.is_open()) {
    throw runtime_error("file not found");
}

string line;
vector<char> lineVec;
while (getline(map, line)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (signed)line.size(); i++) {

        lineVec.push_back((char)line[i]);
    }
    mapMatrix.push_back(lineVec);
    lineVec.clear();
}

return mapMatrix;
```

The .txt file looks something like this:

```
10
10
MMMMMMMMMM
M6...   pM
MMMM.. MMM
MMM... xMM
M..... xxM
M....ggxxM
M MMMMMMMM
M.M..... M
M...OO..PM
MMMMMMMMMM
```

And in the while-loop the first line looks something like this:

```
[size]: 2
[capacity]: 15
[allocator]: allocator
[0]: 49 '1'
[1]: 48 '0'
[Rohdatenansicht]: {_Mypair=allocator }
```

and I dont know where the 49 and 48 are coming from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201622/discussion-on-question-by-cpt-crazy-c-getline-line-has-weird-numbers-additi).

Comment: 49 and 48 is the integer representation of '1' and '0' and that is the first line of you file. Your code must skip first two lines.